# How do you play guitar dead notes quickly switching?

Tags: guitar, technique, electric-guitar

I'm trying to play part of a song that looks like this:

```
0 x x 0 x x 7 x x x  
9 x x 5 x x 5 x x x
```

I find it very difficult to play this. I have trouble playing open strings and letting them ring while fretting the other one. And I have a lot of trouble "deadening" (not palm muting) notes without their harmonics ringing. This song is sort of fast so that makes it worse in combination.

I'm not a beginner, I'm just not used to this technique.  Can you help?

Comment: You just need to mute where there's no harmonic. Try muting with the middle finger, which should be over the 6th fret.

Comment: There are some really high harmonics close to the nut; you an avoid them by muting with two or more fingers together. But for speed, you don't want to move your hand more than necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listening to the sound on the YT video, one part of the key to playing this is to get that chugga-chugga muted sound going.  To do that, mute with more than one finger on your left hand (I'd probably use four, if possible), that should make it less likely that you get harmonics singing.

When it comes to the fretted notes, I'd pay careful attention to make sure just the tip of my finger is fretting the note, and that the tip is as perpendicular to the fretboard as possible, thus building an arch around the high E string so it can ring properly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid harmonics ringing, you need to avoid muting where harmonics are easy (ie avoid your 5th, 7th, 12th frets etc and go for something like 6th or 8th fret which really deaden a string)